# Pivoting table, while preserving all columns not involved

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This code will generate a very simple dummy dataframe, where people filled a survey form:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['John','John','John','Rachel','Rachel','Rachel'],
    'gender':['Male','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female'],
    'age':[40,40,40,39,39,39],
    'SurveyQuestion':['Married?','HasKids?','Smokes?','Married?','HasKids?','Smokes?'],
    'answers':['Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','No']
})
```

The output looks like so:

[image]

Because of the way the table is structured, with each question having its own row, we see that the first 3 columns always contain the same info, as it's just repeating the info based on the person that filled in the survey.

It would be better to visualize the dataframe as a pivot-table, similar to the following:

```
df2.pivot(index='name',columns='SurveyQuestion',values='answers')
```

[image: img]

However, doing it this way results in many of the previous columns being lost, since only 1 column can be used as the index.

I'm wondering what the most straightforward way of doing this would be that didn't involve an extra step  of rejoining the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)**:

```
In [27]: df2.pivot_table(values='answers', index=['name','gender','age'], columns='SurveyQuestion', aggfunc='first')
Out[27]: 
SurveyQuestion    HasKids? Married? Smokes?
name   gender age                          
John   Male   40       Yes      Yes      No
Rachel Female 39        No      Yes      No
```

OR, you can use **[`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)** with **[`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)**, like this:

```
In [30]: df = df2.set_index(['name', 'gender', 'age'])
In [32]: df.pivot(index=df.index, columns='SurveyQuestion')['answers']
Out[32]: 
SurveyQuestion    HasKids? Married? Smokes?
name   gender age                          
John   Male   40       Yes      Yes      No
Rachel Female 39        No      Yes      No
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's any existing algorithms to do this for you but I've had a similar problem in my projects.

If you're trying to condense the rows in your table, first you need to make sure every person can have the same columns applied to them. For example, you can't reasonably do this if you didn't ask the 'HasKids?' question to Rachel unless you include an N/a option.

After this, order the table by some unique ID, that way any repeated people will definitely be next to each other in the table.

Then iterate through this table, and everytime you hit a row that's the same as the last, take whatever unique information it has, add it to the original row for that person and delete this repeat. If this is done for the whole table you should get your pivot.